# CSS- text moves up

Tags: html, css

I have kind of titles on my website which looks like this:

[image]

The problem appears when I rezise the window:

[image]

My text is being moved up and I want it to stretch down. Here is my HTML code:

```
            <div class="inner, header2">
                <div class="first">

                    <img src="images/clean/kim_icon.png" alt="" />
                </div>
                <div class="second">
                    <p class="section">S.I.M.B.A. (Smart Infant Management and Breath Aid)</p>
                </div>
            </div>
```

And my CSS:

```
.header2 {
text-align: left;
padding: 3em 6em 0em 6em;
overflow: hidden;
position: relative;
}

.first { //image
float: left;
}

.second { //text
float: left;
position: absolute;
bottom: 0em;
left: 12em;
}

p{
font-size: 2.75em;
margin-bottom: 1em;
line-height: 100%;
margin: 0 0 2em 0;
}
```

Comment: Research and read about CSS media queries - If I understand what you're asking

Comment: @DarrenSweeney I know what it is, and I am using it but it doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: You can try setting `font-size` in `vw` or `vh` units - that way it's size will depend on width or height of viewport

Comment: @fen1x it didin't work. Still the same problem.

Comment: Can you explain exactly what you're expecting? What does `My text is being moved up and I want it to stretch down` mean?

Comment: Four things: **1.** The entire problem is that you have `bottom: 0` set.  This "pins" the element to the _bottom_, but you want it "pinned" to the top.  Remove `bottom: 0` and add `top: 0`.  **2.** NOTE: 0 is unitless, so `0em` is actually incorrect, should just be `0`).  **3**. Choose _either_ `float` **or** `position: absolute`, but not both.  These are contradictory to each other.  Something that is position absolute will not float.  **4.** This does not do what you want: `class="inner, header2"` - it should simply be space-separated: `class="inner header2"`

Answer (score 0):

An option is to use a flexbox. The text will be placed at the bottom where possible.

```css
.header2 {
  display: flex;
}

.second {
  align-self: flex-end;
}

p {
  font-size: 2.75em;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="inner header2">
  <div class="first">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/100" alt="" />
  </div>
  <div class="second">
    <p class="section">S.I.M.B.A. (Smart Infant Management and Breath Aid)</p>
  </div>
</div>
```